# return AUTO_INCREMENT key from Stored Procedure/Function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a Question about MYSQL Stored Procedure

I have a table "student" and it has a 3 columns

- ID - int(10) -AUTO_INCREMENT
- Name- varchar(255)
- Age-int(10)

the **'ID'** is auto incremental column.
so I want to create  Stored Procedure or function  for insert data to this table and get auto incremental key **(return AUTO_INCREMENT key  from Stored Procedure).**

thank you

Comment: Is the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function what you're looking for?

Comment: Please show the header of the Stored Procedure